# SSRS reporting with multiple values for date row in dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

So I am building a SSRS report that uses multiple datasets(at the moment, for testing), but the main dataset "getData" houses the original query. The problem I am running into is that I seem to be at a lose on how to query through the dataset to grab the data I want for the specific date, title and the value corresponding the that date and title. Here are pictures of most of what I am trying to use. [image: DatasetQueryFields]

[image: DataQuery]

[image: datasetQueryresults]

[image: SSRS format]

So as you can see, If I want the value for Customer Suppot on  Thursday before the 09-12-2015 then I want to extract just that value. How do I approach this? I built another dataset which was using the same query as the dataset above but I added a filter to it for just Thursday before the 9-12-2015. But I seem to only hit the first values of that dataset and the Lookup statement just gives me empty cell. So I am a lost here. Please hints and help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use parameters?   Build a drill-through?   I'm not sure how and when you know what data the user wants to look at.

Comment: No the way it works is if the employee has worked 4 hours on each  customer service and General for say Thursday 09-12-2015 then my report should extract that data and show it. Its a time sheet.